# How to trigger jquery ui dialog box to open when upload begins

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

**I have a form to perform uploads:**

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "assets", :action => "create", :id => @question.id}, :multipart => true) do %>  
    <%= label_tag("file", "Attachment:") %><%= file_field_tag "uploadfile" %><br />
    <%= label_tag("description", "Description") %><br />
    <%= text_area_tag("description",{}, :size => "70x6") %>
    <%= submit_tag("Upload", :class => "register_submit_buttons") %> 
<% end %>
```

The form submits perfectly, and the file begins to upload to amazon s3. What i would like to do is to trigger a jquery ui dialog box to open when upload begins(the moment i click submit on the form) and then close it when the upload has been completed. I already know how to open a dialog when triggered by a link like this:

**link to my dialog div:**

```
<%= link_to("Open dialog", {}, :class => "open-dialog") %>
```

**the dialog div:**

```
<div class="dialog" title="Title">
    ...contents of div
</div>
```

**and finally in my application.js**

```
$(function() {
    $( '.dialog' ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 530,
        modal: true,
        //closeOnEscape: false,
    });
    $('.open-dialog').click(function(){
        $('.dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see most of the stuff is pretty standard from jquery ui website. I would also like to add a button to the dialog box to cancel the upload. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the jQuery submit() listener for the form - this will fire when the form is submitted (and presumably when the upload starts).

eg:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //show box in here
    alert('lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');
});
```

EDIT:

Not sure about how to cancel the upload though, sorry.
But you might get some enlightenment from here: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

jQuery submit(); docs: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: thanks for the link, will look into it, and the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
     $('.dialog' ).dialag('open');
});
```

this opens the dialog and submits the form. Of course if the FORM is not AJAX your dialaog will be closed as soon as the file is uploaded because you are redirected to another page.